# How to get event invitees fom Facebook API?

Tags: php, facebook

How can I get the numbers of attending, unsure, declined from an Facebook event using Facebook PHP API? I know the event id. Do I need any permission? When running the script I want the numbers of  attending, unsure, declined member, just a number, I don't need any personal information.

Can someone help, or give me some source where I can find an answer for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the Facebook Developers Blog for event management : https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/560/

And for a PHP wrapper : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/